# Язык Си, при передачи массива в функцию теряются 3 байта

Tags: c, массивы, строки, функции, указатели

Передаю массив в функцию таким образом не потому что мне так нравится, так требуется в задании.

В функции массив становится меньше на 3 байта, подскажите в чем причина

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* foo(char* in)
{ 
    printf("%i\n", sizeof(in));  // 8 байт
}

int main()
{
    char message[11] = "hello world";
    printf("%i\n", sizeof(SIZE));    // 11 байт
    foo(message);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(in)` у вас отображает размер указателя, а не размер переданного массива. Через указатель вообще не передается размер массива, только указатель на его начало.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первое -

```
char message[11] = "hello world";
```

не указывайте размер, его и так вычислит компилятор. Тем более что 11 символов - не хватает одного для нулевого завершающего символа...

```
char message[] = "hello world";
```

Во-вторых,

```
sizeof(SIZE)
```

что такое здесь `SIZE`?

В третьих,

```
char* foo(char* in)
{ 
    printf("%i\n", sizeof(in));  // 8 байт
}
```

вы спрашиваете о размере указателя `char*` - а он в 64-разрядной системе 8 байт. Чтобы узнать длину С-строки, надо спросить

```
strlen(in);
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло!